# SDL2 audio issues C programming (not mixer)

Tags: c, audio, sdl, sdl-2

I struggle with playing sound in C.

here my function :

```
void playSound(char* path)
{
    SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;
    Uint32 wavLength;
    Uint8 *wavBuffer;

    SDL_LoadWAV(path, &wavSpec, &wavBuffer, &wavLength);
    SDL_AudioDeviceID deviceId = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &wavSpec, NULL, 0);
    SDL_QueueAudio(deviceId, wavBuffer, wavLength);
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(deviceId, 0);

    if (SDL_GetQueuedAudioSize(deviceId) == 0) {

        SDL_CloseAudioDevice(deviceId);
        SDL_FreeWAV(wavBuffer);
    }
}
```

The sound will play several times and then won't play again.

I check SDL_GetQueuedAudioSize, and when he is reaching  0, no more sound is playing.

I think its about buffer when is empty.. dunno i misunderstand some point.

I am not allowed to use another lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found

it may help: 
in .h

```
typedef struct son_s {
    SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;
    Uint32 wavLength;
    Uint8 *wavBuffer;
    SDL_AudioDeviceID deviceId;

}son_t;
```

if lot of sound, you make a structure array.

in .c file

```
void closeAudio(son_t* son)
{
    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(son->deviceId);
}

son_t* initAudio(char* path)
{
    son_t* son = malloc(sizeof(son_t));
    if (!son) {
        return NULL ;
    }
    SDL_LoadWAV(path, &son->wavSpec, &son->wavBuffer, &son->wavLength);
    son->deviceId = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &son->wavSpec, NULL, 0);
    return son;
}

void playSound(son_t* son)
{
    SDL_QueueAudio(son->deviceId, son->wavBuffer, son->wavLength);
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(son->deviceId, 0);

   if (SDL_GetQueuedAudioSize(son->deviceId) == 0) {
        SDL_FreeWAV(son->wavBuffer);
    }
}
```